# Hibernate: How to define composite key with one attriubte in parent entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, composite-key

lets assume I have two Entities:

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<PriceGroup> priceGroups = new ArrayList<PriceGroup>();
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Page {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String pageNumber;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    private Book book;
}
```

Now I want to prevent, that somebody create two pages with the same pageNumber for the same Book.

I tried @NaturalId, but I cannot figure out how to combine the Book.id with its pageNumber attribute. I only found solutions for primitive attributes that both were in the Page entity.

Can you help?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be creating unique contraint on page_number and book_id. If you want stick composite primary key, then you want to use @Embeddable and @EmbeddedId Example: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-composite-primary-key-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Answer (score 0):

Use a unique constraint through `@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(...))`